# Prepend text to standard input

Tags: shell-script, pipe

I have a script, `script1`, that operates on standard input.
I can call that script from `script2`

```
#!/bin/sh

./script1
```

`script1` then operates on standard input to `script2`. I can also pipe some other input to `script1`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Called from script2" | ./script1
```

But then `./script1` does not use the standard input at all.

What I want is to prepend the standard input to `script1` by the input "Called from script2". Is this possible?

I know how to do this with a temp file, but I am wondering if there's a way to not use a temporary file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

{
    echo 'some text'
    cat
} | ./script1
```

or

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

{ echo 'some text'; cat; } | ./script1
```

Use `cat` to forward the standard input of your wrapper script to `script1`.

In the examples above, I pipe the combined output of the preceding compound command (the `{ ...; }` bit) to your `script1` script.  The input of `cat` is the standard input stream of your wrapper script, and `cat` would reproduce it on its output stream after `echo` has produced its output.